# Use a domain name for an SPA and API

Tags: azure, rest, url, azure-functions, single-page-application

I have an React SPA that is hosted on Azure static Websites and the domain is currently managed through a different domain name company (happy to move it to Azure but haven't needed to at present)

The SPA has the usual structure or a website.

However i have a number of Azure functions I want to offer as a service, but I don't want to make the Azure Function urls known to the public, more for readability and professionalism than anything

So I would like to use the same domain name that is used on the SPA to allow the users to access the Azure Functions

eg

currently I have

[www.mydomain.com/products](http://www.mydomain.com/products)
[www.mydomain.com/about](http://www.mydomain.com/about)

and i want to mask the azure functions using my domain name using an prefix of "api"

so

[www.mydomain.com/api/product/{id}](http://www.mydomain.com/api/product/%7Bid%7D)
[www.mydomain.com/api/products?page=1](http://www.mydomain.com/api/products?page=1)

but I have no idea where to start any advice would be appriciated

Comment: Have you looked at [`Azure Static Web Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview)? It will let you host both your SPA and Function App together.

Comment: thats exactly what i have written and said I am doing, but there is nothing in the docs to say i can use a custom domain name to call azure functions while its also being used for a website

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible just as you want. Can you use something like www.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com?

Comment: BTW, you should avoid of using AzFunctions directly published to Internet. Better to use API Management, it will bring much more security. API Management also support custom domains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain?tabs=custom

Comment: api.mydomain.com would be a possability but would prefer www.mydomain.com/api/ if possible, will take a look at api management, but azure keeps getting more and more expensive.